# How can I create an "enum" type property value dynamically

Tags: vb.net, list, properties, dictionary, enums

I need to create a property in a class that will give the programmer a list of values to choose from. I have done this in the past using the enums type.

```
Public Enum FileType
    Sales
    SalesOldType
End Enum

Public Property ServiceID() As enFileType
    Get
        Return m_enFileType
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As enenFileType)
        m_enFileType = value
    End Set
End Property
```

The problem is I would like to populate the list of values on init of the class based on SQL table values. From what I have read it is not possible to create the enums on the fly since they are basically constants.

Is there a way I can accomplish my goal possibly using list or dictionary types?
OR any other method that may work.

Comment: How would you ever use the values if you don't know what they are at compile time?  Are you simply looking to auto-generate code before compiling?

Comment: That is the problem. I need the values to come from a table and be loaded in the class property in a way that will allow the programmer to choose from the selections.

Comment: So the values aren't going to change once the code is compiled?

Comment: Correct, The idea is that when a new Item is added to the table the choice to use it for a developer would be updated without having to change the code in this class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the values aren't going to change after the code is compiled, then it sounds like the best option is to simply auto-generate the code.  For instance, you could write a simple application that does something like this:

```
Public Shared Sub Main()
    Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
    builder.AppendLine("' Auto-generated code.  Don't touch!!  Any changes will be automatically overwritten.")
    builder.AppendLine("Public Enum FileType")
    For Each pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In GetFileTypesFromDb()
        builder.AppendLine(String.Format("    {0} = {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value))
    End For
    builder.AppendLine("End Enum")
    File.WriteAllText("FileTypes.vb", builder.ToString())
End Sub

Public Function GetFileTypesFromDb() As Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    '...
End Function
```

Then, you could add that application as a pre-build step in your project so that it automatically runs each time you compile your main application.

Comment: This is for a class that lives in a class Library. so when would this code run? each time the class is updated or referenced?

Comment: You would need to manually recompile the class library after updating the database.

Comment: Have you considered changing your primary source for the data?  If the source code was the official primary location for the data, then it would just be a matter of keeping the database automatically updated when the source code changed, which may be easier I think. Or better yet, if its only necessary to have the list in the code, you could ditch that database table altogether.

Comment: Changing the data store location is not possible here. The data is actually created from another application. My hope was that I could write code to generate this class based on the data already collected from the other app. Your solution is the closest I have found to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will answer your question, but its just my opinion on the matter. I like enums, mostly because they are convenient for me, the programmer. This is just because when I am writing code, using and enum over a constant value gives me not only auto-complete when typing, but also the the compile time error checking that makes sure I can only give valid enum values. However, enums just don't work for run-time defined values, since, like you say, there are compile time defined constants.

Typically, when I use flexible values that are load from an SQL Table like in your example, I'll just use string values. So I would just store `Sales` and `SalesOldType` in the table and use them for the value of `FileType`. I usually use strings and not integers, just because strings are human readable if I'm looking at data tables while debugging something.

Now, you can do a bit of a hybrid, allowing the values to be stored and come from the table, but defining commonly used values as constants in code, sorta like this:

```
 Public Class FileTypeConstants
       public const Sales = "Sales"
       public const SalesOldType = "SalesOldType"
 End Class
```

That way you can make sure when coding with common values, a small string typo in one spot doesn't cause a bug in your program.

Also, as a side note, I write code for and application that is deployed internally to our company via click-once deployment, so for seldom added values, I will still use an enum because its extremely easy to add a value and push out an update. So the question of using and enum versus database values can be one of how easy it is to get updates to your users. If you seldom update, database values are probably best, if you update often and the updates are not done by users, then enums can still work just as well.

Hope some of that helps you!

Comment: +1. From my experience, strings work AS IS, i.e. making corresponding consts only complicates things in the long run.

Comment: You said, "compile time error checking that makes sure I can only give valid enum values," but that's not true, you can always set any enum-typed variable to any integer value.

Comment: @StevenDoggart, yes you are technically correct, the best kind of correct. I guess it was more that it would be possible to write `FileType = "Slase"`, where `FileType = FileType.Slase` would not even compile.